# Run npm install programmatically in specified folder

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to run `npm install` via typescript code in a specified directory.

I found this code:

```
npm.load({}, function(err: any) {
    // handle errors

    // install module ffi
    npm.commands.install(["hello-world@0.0.1"], function(err: any, data: any) {
    // log errors or data
    });

    npm.on('log', function(message: any) {
    // log installation progress
    console.log(message);
    });
});
```

But now I don't want to install `hello-world`, but just run `npm install` (without any package).

Additionally it should run in a path that I can specify, like `./folder/subfolder`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from exec it's also possible to use the npm package:

```
import * as cp from 'child_process';
var npm = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'npm.cmd' : 'npm';

var path = '/path_to_npm_install';
const result = cp.spawnSync( npm, ['install'], {
     cwd: path
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Nodejs, which I think you are, you can run

```
child_process.exec('npm install') // or any other command which you give from terminal or command prompt
```

Check the documentation for child_process 
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nodejs `script` that expect the directory path from user and create a child process and execute that command in that.

index.js

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec(`cd /${process.env.PATH} | npm install`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});


PATH=/path_of_directory_to_run_npm_install node index.js
```

Read more about `child_process` from nodejs documentation - https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback